# High speed design using FPGA

Tags: signal-processing

I'm designing high speed FIR filter ON FPGA  .Currently My sampling rate is 3600MSPS. But the clock supported by device is 350MHZ.Please suggest how to go with multiple instantiation 
or parallel implementation of FIR Filter so that it meets the design requirement.

Also suggest how to pass samples to the parallel implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question based on the information you have given.

The first question I would ask myself is: can you reduce the sample rate at all? 3600 MSPS is very high. The sample rate only needs to be this high if you are truely supporting data requiring that bandwidth.

Assuming you do really need that rate, then in order to implement an FIR filter running at such a high sample rate, you will need to parallelise the architecture as you suggested. It's generally very easy to implement such a structure. An example approach is shown here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Processing_%28DSP_implementation%29#Parallel_FIR_Filters

Each clock cycle you will pass a parallel word into each filter section, and extract a word from the combined filter output.

But only you know the requirements and constraints of your FPGA design; you will have to craft the FIR filter according to your requirements.